# rails multiple has_many relationships between the same models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, relational-database

I'm trying to figure out the best way to model a many-to-one relationship in rails where there are multiple scopes to the relationship.

An example would be a restaurant has-many photos. I want to be able to call

```
restaurant.lounge_photos
```

and receive only the lounge photos,
but also be able to call

```
restaurant.food_photos
```

and receive just the food photos.

The two methods I can think of are:

1. to use multiple joins table, and a has_many to has_one relationship for each type of photo.
2. to add a 'type' attribute to the photo model and write a scoping method.

Both of these seem a bit clunky to me. 
Is there a better solution here?

Comment: Scoping is the common aproach.

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to go **has_many** and **Single Table Inheritance(STI)**, as follow.

1. Make association with `restaurant` and `photo`

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

2. Then you have to use STI in `Photo` model. The reason is that you have almost all fields are common for `lounge_photos` and `food_photos`.

OR

Using scope directly you can differentiate it and achieve your goal.

For more details of use STI you can refer [this link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/single-table-inheritance-vs-polymorphic-associations-in-rails-af3a07a204f2).

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, using a `type` column

```
has_many :food_photos, 
         class_name: 'Photo', 
         foreign_key: :restaurant_id, 
         -> { where(type: 'food') }

has_many :lounge_photos, 
         class_name: 'Photo', 
         foreign_key: :restaurant_id, 
         -> { where(type: 'lounge') }
```